# Using basename() to grab a part of file path

Tags: php, regex

Continuing with my series of questions in the past month or so, I am stuck with one more thing. Just when I thought I am getting a hang of RegEx and I can handle things better now, I have a new problem.
I have the same text file.

Here's a quick look at it:

```
================================================
Header of File with time and date
================================================
Loaded options from XML file: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/ID2PDF_options.xml
extendedPrintPDF started
Postfix '3.0' was append from file 'ESQ030112ELAM_lo-metadata.xml' for file: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.indd
    printPDF started
    PDF Export Preset: Some preset
    PDF file created: ''/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.pdf'.
File someFileName.xml removed
postprocessingDocument started
INDD file removed: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.indd
================================================
Header of File with time and date
================================================
Loaded options from XML file: ''/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/COS/Contract_Proof_COS/processing/ID2PDF_options.xml
extendedPrintPDF started
Postfix '8.1' was append from file 'ESQ030112Politics_Russia_lo-metadata.xml' for file: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/COS/Contract_Proof_COS/processing/oneMoreFile.indd
    printPDF started
    PDF Export Preset: Hearst PDF 1.6_1_16_08
    PDF file created: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/COS/Contract_Proof_COS/processing/oneMoreFile.pdf'.
File oneMoreFile.xml removed
postprocessingDocument started
INDD file removed: /Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/COS/Contract_Proof_COS/processing/oneMoreFile.indd
```

I'm using the following RegEx, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
/^Loaded options from XML file: '/Thisis/some/Users/.*/SM_Folder/([a-zA-Z]{3})/Contract_Proof_\1/processing/ID2PDF_options.xml'$/im
```

Gives an error "Unknown modifier T'.

I would like to catch the ESQ and COS from the first line of each entry in an array. 
P.S. Seems easy, but here's the catch or may be not.

```
1. The username may change. So, I can't create a RegEx relying on username.
2. The COS, ESQ, etc. would repeat further in the entries. But, I only need to catch the FIRST occurrence in each entry.
```

Can I have any hints/suggestions about how I can do this?! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scape the `/` because the `/` delimites the end of the regex.

`le: '/Thisis/` Here's where you have the problem, after the `/` you've got a `T` and it's not a known modifier for Regular Expressions.

You scape special meaning characters with `\` so if you want to scape the `/` you must use `\/`

Comment: @WatchfulProtector Explained better.

Comment: Okay. that solved it. But, now it says unknown modifier 'o'. I wonder where that comes from. Because none of the words seem to start with an 'o' or 'O'. Can you please help me understand this better?

Comment: Okay. So, I've got to
         /^Loaded options from XML file: '\/.*\/SM_Folder\/([a-zA-Z]{3})\/[a-zA-Z]_Proof_\1\/processing\/ID2PDF_options.xml'$/im 
now. But, all I get is an EMPTY array. And if I take off the \ before /(a-zA-Z), I get "unknown modifier '('". 
How do I tackle this?